# App screenshot taken before I can hide the view when moving into the background

Tags: ios, background

I'm trying to implement something similar to the functionality detailed here by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1838/_index.html

Instead of putting up a view controller when the app goes into the background, I'm trying to put it in place when `applicationWillResignActive` is called instead.

The problem I am having is that the screenshot seems to be taken before the view controller is rendered. When I reopen the app, I see a flicker of the blocking view controller before it gets dismissed in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

If I put the app fully into the background, then I see the blocking view, but if I just double-tap the home button to view the app switcher, nothing happens.

This works ok on the iPhone X when I swipe up to view the application switcher, but I can't get it to work on iPhone 5, 6 or iPad Mini.

What am I missing here?

Code is below:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    DDLogInfo(@"Application did resign active");
    [self showBlockingView];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    DDLogInfo(@"Application did become active");
    [self hideBlockingview];
}

-(void)showBlockingView {
    self.blockingView = [UIView new];
    self.blockingView.backgroundColor = [DCMStyleManager lightGray];
    self.blockingView.frame = self.window.bounds;

    [self.window addSubview:self.blockingView];

}

-(void)hideBlockingview {
    [self.blockingView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**edit:**
I have also read on here that the screenshot is not taken until the app is actually in the background, and that the view you see in the App Switcher is a live view? I just tried adding a basic animation to the view to see if it was actually live, but everything freezes as soon as it shows the switcher.

Comment: Why not using `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: Because I need to hide information when the app goes into the app switcher, so those methods are not triggered.